# antlr4-tool fails in Win10 with: Error: Command failed: which java

Tags: node.js, npm, antlr, antlr4

Running in Win10, in an attempt to create a parser in Node.JS, I installed ANTLR4 tool:

```
npm install --save-dev antlr4-tool
```

Ran:

```
c:/prj/parser/node_modules/.bin/antlr4-tool.cmd -o parser grammar/Lang.g4
```

But received:

```
Compiling grammar/Lang.g4...
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
child_process.js:677
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: which java
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:674:13)
    at c:\prj\parser\node_modules\antlr4-tool\dist\antlr-core\antlr-compiler.js:98:19
    at chdir (c:\prj\parser\node_modules\chdir\index.js:6:13)
    at AntlrCompiler.compileJavaScript (c:\prj\parser\node_modules\antlr4-tool\dist\antlr-core\antlr-compiler.js:97:9)
    at AntlrCompiler.compileTypeScript (c:\prj\parser\node_modules\antlr4-tool\dist\antlr-core\antlr-compiler.js:62:38)
    at c:\prj\parser\node_modules\antlr4-tool\dist\antlr-core\index.js:40:78
    at c:\prj\parser\node_modules\antlr4-tool\dist\antlr-core\index.js:17:23
    at arrayEach (c:\prj\parser\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:516:11)
    at Function.forEach (c:\prj\parser\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9344:14)
```

I have Java install, and I can see its location when running:

```
where java
```

But since I'm in Windows, I don't understand why the command is `which` and not `where`...

Answer (score 2):

To whomever gets here, it's a bug, apprently stemming from the difference between Linux and Windows (`which` command in Linux is `where` in Windows).

To W/A it, ***only if you work in Windows***, change the file:

`.../node_modules/antlr4-tool/dist/antlr-core/antlr-compiler.js`, line #98, from:

```
child.execSync('which java');
```

to:

```
child.execSync('where java');
```

See https://github.com/mcchatman8009/antlr4-tool/issues/21

Comment: Great! Solved my problem, Thanks!